# Print HTML Table from an array with condition with Perl CGI

Tags: html, perl, cgi

i have made a script that returns me an array with several lines like :

> DATA:VALUE:VALUE_MAX

I need to fill a table with those value like :

```
NAME |  Status
--------------------------
DATA |  OK/minor/warning...
.... |  .........
.... |  .........
```

with VALUE and VALUE_MAX i calculate the percent wich give me the status.

here is my code for print the table :

```
my @i = my_status();

print <<END;
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
END
my $inc = 0;
while (@i) {
my @temp = split /:/, @i[$inc];
my $name = $temp[0];
my $percent = ($temp[1] * $temp[2] / 100);
my $status = undef;
if ($percent <= 24 ) {
print "<tr class='info'>";
$status = "Critical !";
}
elsif ($percent <= 49 ) {
print "<tr class='danger'>";
$status = "Danger !";
}
elsif ($percent <= 74 ) {
print "<tr class='warning'>";
$status = "Warning";
}
elsif ($percent <= 99 ) {
print "<tr class='active'>";
$status = "Minor";
}
elsif ($percent == 100 ) {
print "<tr class='success'>";
$status = "OK";
}
print "<td>$name</td>";
print "<td>$status</td>";
print "</tr>";
$inc++;
}
print <<END;
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
END
```

My script "my_status" is a bit long to execute, it's full of server request...

but the thing is, on the HTML page, everything is a mess, i get wrong value, and an endless loop who print only "Critical !" in status colomns

what is wrong with my script ?

Comment: Why does _critical_ have the class `info`?

Comment: @simbabque it's just class for the color, i will change it after, in fact i have multiple tables to fill with those value, it's just a way to make it work in the first place ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **not** iterating `@i` in your `while` loop. Your line

```
while (@i) {
```

means that it will stay in the loop as long as `@i` is true. Because that's an array, that means that as long as there are items in `@i`, it will stay in the loop.

You do not remove anything from `@i` inside of the loop. There are no `shift` or `pop` commands, and you also do not overwrite `@i`. So it will stay indefinitely. You've got yourself an infinite loop.

---

What you want instead is probably a `foreach` loop. Then you also don't need `$inc`. It will put each element inside of `@i` into `$elem` and run the loop.

```
foreach my $elem (@i) {
    my @temp    = split /:/, $elem;
    my $name    = $temp[0];
    my $percent = ( $temp[1] * $temp[2] / 100 );
    my $status  = undef;
    if ( $percent <= 24 ) {
        print "<tr class='info'>";
        $status = "Critical !";
    }
    elsif ( $percent <= 49 ) {
        print "<tr class='danger'>";
        $status = "Danger !";
    }
    elsif ( $percent <= 74 ) {
        print "<tr class='warning'>";
        $status = "Warning";
    }
    elsif ( $percent <= 99 ) {
        print "<tr class='active'>";
        $status = "Minor";
    }
    elsif ( $percent == 100 ) {
        print "<tr class='success'>";
        $status = "OK";
    }
    print "<td>$name</td>";
    print "<td>$status</td>";
    print "</tr>";
}
```

You can read up on loops in [perlsyn starting from *for loops*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops).